# PHP - How to set https headers to soap ws request

Tags: php, soap, https, http-headers, soapui

I'm using SoapUI 5.3.0 to test a SOAP ws request.
I was requested to send user and password via https headers not via soap headers.
It works well when I use this SoapUi tool:

[image: SoapUI 5.3.0 Capture]
However, when I try to do it from php I always get an authentication error, exactly the same error I get when I use a wrong password on purpose, I've tried several combinations but none of them gave me expected results

code example:

```
$data['Contrato'] = '123456';
$data['FechaInicio'] = '11/07/2017';
$data['FechaFin'] ='11/07/2017';

$client = new SoapClient( "https://example.com/WebService?WSDL", array(
    "exceptions" => 0,
    "trace" => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => 'Username:xxx@gmail.com\\n\\r Password:notrealpwd'
        ),
    )),
));

$result = $client->__soapCall('depositos', $data);
```

Does any of you knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I finished using curl to set the needed headers, that solved it.

```
<?php 
// xml post structure
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hub="https://example.com/WebService?WSDL">
                       <soapenv:Header/>
                       <soapenv:Body>
                          <hub:depositos>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <hub:solicitud>
                                <Contrato>123456</Contrato>
                                <FechaInicio>11/07/2017</FechaInicio>
                                <!--Optional:-->
                                <FechaFin>11/07/2017</FechaFin>
                             </hub:solicitud>
                          </hub:depositos>
                       </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: ''",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    "Username: xxx@gmail.com",
    "Password: notrealpwd"
);

// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ws_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0,
                 "login" => $login, "password" => $password) );
```